# From Range Partition to Range-Interval

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-partitioning

I would like to move from Range Partition to Range-Interval, but my current table has a partition on `MAXVALUE` and the column used for partitioning allows null values :(

E.g.: Say we have:

```
create table a (b number)
partition by range (b) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (50),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Then we populate:

```
INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (11);
INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (51);
INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (null);
```

To be able to move to interval, we need to remove the partition with `MAXVALUE`, therefore, other values should be moved to a new partition.
51 is not a problem, I would create partition where with `VALUES LESS than 100`, but what about `NULL` ones?

I was thinking about changing to something like  partition by range `(NVL(b,0))`, but I am scared about that having to reprocess the whole table (not possible, real table has a lot of data).

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can't have `NULL` in the partition key column of an interval partitioned table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7002.htm#BABGCEFI) (as of 12.1):

> **Restrictions on Interval Partitioning**
>
> - You can specify **only one partitioning key column**, and it must be of
>     NUMBER, DATE, FLOAT, or TIMESTAMP data type.
>
> [...]
>
> - You cannot specify NULL values for the partitioning key column.

You can't use expressions either for the partitioning key. However as suggested by [@Shoelace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3825/shoelace) you can use a virtual column (containing your expression) as a partition column:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE a (b NUMBER, comput_b NUMBER AS (NVL(b, 0)))
  2  PARTITION BY RANGE (comput_b) (
  3    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0),
  4    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (50),
  5    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
  6  );

Table created

SQL> INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (1);
1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (11);
1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (51);
1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO a(b) VALUES (null);
1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT * FROM a;

         B   COMPUT_B
---------- ----------
         1          1
        11         11
                    0
        51         51
```

In this particular case I think you would need a table rebuild.

Comment: thats not exactly true. since at least 11g you can create a virtual column (which is just an expression)  and use that to partition by...

Comment: @ShoeLace Thanks, I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_interval_partitioning.htm](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_interval_partitioning.htm%20This) says you can change range to interval and back again by using the `alter table` syntax

ie

```
alter table a set INTERVAL(100) ;
```

the full alter table syntax for 11g is available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001).

unfortunately that does not seem to allow you to change partition columns ..  so i think you are out of luck. but you can always try.